# Can't access a partion that has a virus on it

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, anti-virus, virus

My wife's computer had a virus alarm go off, so I am looking into it.

The virus is supposed to be on the D: drive.

I wanted to talk a quick look at the file, but I cannot not.

It has one file that I can get to.  It is D:\Recovery.

That shows a "Protected by PC Angel" graphic.

How can I get past this?  Should I do it?  Is the virus scanner wrong? (I am using Avast).

I don't know if it matters, but the file that Avast sees as a virus is:

D:\i386\Apps\App002216\wtsetup-english.exe\$_OUTDIR\emachines\tradewinds-oem.exe\$INSTDIR\tradewinds-WT.exe[Embedded_O#0e7000]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the virus scanner blocks access to protect you (and possibly - that either it or the virus damaged the data on the drive). Check for the quarantine feature (or a similar name).

Comment: I was not clear enough.  The whole drive is blocked off by a program called "PC Angel".  My virus scanner is called Avast.

Answer (score 1):

PC Angel as per this [post](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-get-rid-of-pc-angel) is a Recovery Partition Tool.

So PC Angel is just blocking the recovey folder. The other folders MAY be blocked out by Avast. Or the drive may have got corrupted.

So since you have data stored in D:\, use [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) to boot up your PC, copy the data to C:\ or another backup drive.

Answer (score 0):

The file could be marked as a hidden operating system file.  If this is the case then the file will not be visible using the default windows explorer settings.  Follow this menu path in windows explorer:

Tools->Folder Options->View

Make sure the following radio button is selected:

"Show hidden files and folders"